# Receiving strange number from fscanf - int conversion?

Tags: c, scanf

I am very new to C and having a problem here. I am attempting to pass a file numbers.in through the below script. numbers.in contains 2 lines as follow:

```
12,34,56789
123456,789,0123
```

I am attempting to recognize the comma delineation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{      
  int   p ,n ,x ;   //Converted ints.

  while ( fscanf(stdin,"%d,%d,%d\n",&p,&n,&x) == 3 );
  {
    printf("got the sequence (%d,%d,%d)\n",x,p,n);
  }
}
```

I am running the script like:
./a.out < numbers.in

Currently my script returns completely different numbers! What am I doing wrong here? Is the file sending them as characters so I need to somehow convert to ints? (I tried saving as chars and then later converting chars to ints and also got strange numbers - but different strange numbers!)

### SOLVED, bad semicolon usage >_<

Comment: What numbers does your script return?

Comment: Remove the semicolon behind the while. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  while ( fscanf(stdin,"%d,%d,%d\n",&p,&n,&x) == 3 ); <-- remove this semicolon
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! How embarrassing haha, you are right, that fixed it! (will accept your answer in 8min)